# Focus/emphasis in or on?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I automatically use the preposition *on* after the words *focus* or *emphasis*. However, I've recently come across several instances of them being followed by *in*, such as in the following examples:

> She graduated with a degree in studio art, with a focus in printmaking.

or

> He graduated with a degree in creative writing, with emphasis in fiction.

A quick Google search shows that this is common. I'm not entirely convinced however, and I can't seem to find anything to support the use of *in* in dictionaries or style guides. Any help?

Comment: I would go for "on" for both of these sentences.

Comment: @Javababe No, it is conventional to use *in* to refer to one's academic concentration— a degree *in* civil engineering, a major *in* classical philology, a certificate *in* network security, a specialty *in* fiction writing.

Comment: @choster: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> She graduated with a degree in studio art, with a focus in printmaking.

This is an academic context. In this context, the preposition *in* is often used with the verb *focus* to describe a program's special emphasis.

As an example, have a look at these program listings from a Google search. Notice how they are all hits on academic websites:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'focus' as a ***'verb'***, it takes the preposition 'on'.

[OALD's entry for the verb 'focus'](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/focus_1) gives all examples of sentences with 'on'. However, as I see on other reference sites, I see that 'focus in' is also possible. But the context is different.

Say, if you are taking a snap, you may *focus in* to capture an object. It may serve as 'zoom in'. However, I'm not sure about this usage because your context is different.